# How to split joined array with delimiter into chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, chunks

I have array of strings

```
const arr = ['some', 'word', 'anotherverylongword', 'word', 'yyy', 'u']
const joined = arr.join(';')
```

I want to get array of chunks where joined string length is not greater than 10

for example output would be:

```
[
    ['some;word'], // joined string length not greater than 10
    ['anotherverylongword'], // string length greater than 10, so is separated
    ['word;yyy;u'] // joined string length is 10
]
```

Comment: I don't understand, what should happen with `anotherverylongword`?

Comment: @Wendelin it should just stay in array if its length is greater than 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (with some [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)) to generate such chunks:

```js
const arr = ['some', 'word', 'anotherverylongword', 'word', 'yyy', 'u'];
const chunkSize = 10;

const result = arr.slice(1).reduce(
  (acc, cur) =>
    acc[acc.length - 1].length + cur.length + 1 > chunkSize
      ? [...acc, cur]
      : [...acc.slice(0, -1), `${acc[acc.length - 1]};${cur}`],
  [arr[0]]
);

console.log(result);
```

The idea is building the array with the chunks (`result`) by starting with the first element from `arr` (second parameter to `reduce` function), and then, for each one of the remaining elements of `arr` (`arr.slice(1)`), checking if it can be appended to the the last element of the accumulator (`acc`). The accumulator ultimately becomes the final returning value of `reduce`, assigned to `result`.

Comment: Downvoted for bad readability. Using a function body with if / else statements and `push` instead of spread would increase performance and readability.

Comment: Once you truly get the idea of `reduce`, this becomes quite natural. This is in a more functional style (also the idea of not having assignments, using spread operator, etc.). But I do agree that it can be hard to read in the beginning.

Comment: I have no problem with reduce but the nested ternary operators.

Comment: I see your point. It's a matter of personal taste, I would say. But I managed to simplify the code a bit in the `slice` usage.

Comment: with this solution, if i change `'u'` into `'uu'` it output `[ 'some;word', 'anotherverylongword', 'word;yyy;uu' ]`, and `'word;yyy;uu'` has 11 characters, so is greater than 10, so the `'uu'` should be separated

Comment: Good observation, @user3075373. There was an off-by-one error. Just edited my answer to fix this.

Comment: I'd simplify by starting the accumulator with the first element and reducing the remainder of the array.  I'd also try to work in a few upside-down Spanish question marks, just for fun :-)

Comment: @danh I like that haha. Edited my answer a bit ;)