# Split joined slice with delimiter into chunks of maximum N length

Tags: arrays, go, slice, delimiter, chunks

I have slice of strings

```
s := []string{"some", "word", "anotherverylongword", "word", "yyy", "u"}

delimiter := ";"
```

I want to get another slice of them joined if with delimiter length is less or equal to 10

so output would be:
`{"some;word", "anotherverylongword", "word;yyy;u"}`

"anotherverylongword" has more than 10 characters so its separated, rest has less or exactly 10 characters with delimiter so it's joined.

I asked same question with JavaScript ([How to split joined array with delimiter into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60353704/how-to-split-joined-array-with-delimiter-into-chunks))

but solution was written with immutability in mind.
Go nature is more mutable, and I can't wrap my head around to translate it into Go, that's why I'm asking it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way, some comments added

```
s := []string{"some", "word", "anotherverylongword", "word", "yyy", "u", "kkkk"}
var res []string
var cur string
for i, e := range s {
    if len(cur)+len(e)+1 > 10 { // check adding string exceed chuck limit
        res = append(res, cur)  // append current string
        cur = e                  
    } else {
        if cur != "" {          // add delimeter if not empty string
            cur += ";"
        }
        cur += e
    }
    if i == len(s)-1 {
        res = append(res, cur)
    }
}
```

Code on go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ChnsyzHWyKM)

And more simplified

```
s := []string{"some", "word", "anotherverylongword", "word", "yyy", "u", "kkkk"}
var res []string
for _, e := range s {
    l := len(res)
    if l > 0 && len(res[l-1])+len(e)+1 > 10 {
        res = append(res, e)
    } else {
        if l > 0 {
            res[l-1] += ";" + e
        } else {
            res = append(res, e)
        }
    }
}
```